# print after 1 second in C

Tags: c

Considering the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

const int NUM_SECONDS = 1;

int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    volatile sig_atomic_t flag = false;

    double time_counter = 0;

    clock_t this_time = clock();
    clock_t last_time = this_time;

    printf("Gran = %ld\n", NUM_SECONDS * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    while(1)
        {
            this_time = clock();
            time_counter += (double)(this_time - last_time);
            last_time = this_time;

            if(time_counter > (double)(NUM_SECONDS * CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
                {
                    time_counter -= (double)(NUM_SECONDS * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                    flag = true;
                    count++;
                }
            if (flag == true)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    printf ("%d", count);
                }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The `printf()` prints count as expected IF '\n' is included in the format specifier. It does not print anything with the code above. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Turn off output buffering with `setbuf()`.

Comment: Or use `fflush(stdout)`